# Where do I find the US GDP growth on FRED?

Tags: macroeconomics

I have never used FRED before. **I need to locate the annual growth rate in Real GDP** to do some data analysis for my intro macro class. The TA and the Prof were utterly unhelpful and I'm frankly lost.

Specifically, I think I am supposed to use this site: 
https://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/A191RL1Q225SBEA

If you click on Graph tab, I can adjust the data present. However, there are a bunch of options and I can't tell which one I need.

**MY QUESTION**

(1) Am I looking in the right spot on FRED for the aforementioned information I'm interested in?
(2) If I am in the right spot, which version of the data do I want? Do I want "Percent change from preceding period" or "Percent change from year ago" for example. Also, what aggregation method.

I googled this terms to no avail.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not an economic question but asks as to delve into a professor's mind and guessing what the exact assignment is.

Answer (score 1):

With the link you posted you get quarterly data, so to get the yearly growth rate you need to change the frequency to annual. There are different aggregation methods but if it's not specified in the question you were asked I don't see how one should be more right than another.